# How to merge multiple Zod (object) schema

Tags: typescript, zod

I've 3 schema for a blog post.

1. Image post
2. Video post
3. Text post

Schema look like this

```js
// will be used for form validation

// text can be added but image required
const imagePostSchema = z.object({
  body: z.string().max(500).optional().or(z.literal('')),
  attachmentType: z.literal('img'),
  attachment: // z... image validation is here
});

// text can be added but video required
const videoPostSchema = z.object({
  body: z.string().max(500).optional().or(z.literal('')),
  attachmentType: z.literal('video'),
  attachment: // z... video validation is here
});

// text is required & other fields must be null
const textPostSchema = z.object({
  body: z.string().max(500),
  attachmentType: z.null(),
  attachment: z.null()
});
```

Now how to merge this schema's to make one schema so user can make any type of (this 3) post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merging into a schema that accepts "*any type of these 3*" is done by a [union](https://zod.dev/?id=unions) of the three types, using `….or(…)` or `z.union(…)`. However, since those types are to be distinguished based on their `attachmentType`, you really want a [discriminated union](https://zod.dev/?id=discriminated-unions) which will make checking more efficient:

```
const postSchema = z.discriminatedUnion("attachmentType", [
  imagePostSchema,
  videoPostSchema,
  textPostSchema,
]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you'r solution seems best option, I'm using this schemas with react-hook-form, In there in the `defaultValues`, I was getting excellent auto-completion before, but now I think that reduced but it still works. Is there I'm doing anything wrong or is there any way to improve zod schemas i've?

Comment: @Md.A.Apu You may want to [ask a separate question](/questions/ask) about that, showing how use use react-hook-form and where you expected an autocompletion that you are not (no longer?) getting

Answer (score 0):

To combine schemas in an "or" fashion, use `z.union`.

```
const postSchema = z.union([imagePostSchema, videoPostSchema, textPostSchema]);
```

`postSchema` is now valid for any object that matches any of the 3 schemas.